# Error Giving in Nuget package manager while enable Migrations

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I am developing MVC application with EF 5.0 I am trying to install DBMigration package from Nuget, but its giving an error

```
PM> Enable-Migrations
No context type was found in the assembly 'DBMigrationEXP'.
PM> Enable-Migrations
No context type was found in the assembly 'DBMigrationEXP'.
```

Answer (score 0):

The project dropdown in the package manager needs to have the project with a DbContext in it selected.